# Programmatically access TinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, shopify, tinymce-4

I'm trying to access tinymce editor instance in the shopify's new blog page in order to set it's contents. the 'tinymce' variable is available globally only after I press inspect element and that somehow makes it available in the console, but before that it's undefined and throws an error when I try to access it.

Following content script is injected into all frames and only executed when I manually send an article data through sendMessage from a popup script. In that context I try to access the *tinymce* variable, which is only available after I do the inspect element thing - weird, but ok.

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    const article = message.article as Article;

    try {
        // I expect the window.tinymce to be a TinyMCE instance
        if (window.tinymce) {
            console.log(window.tinymce) // This logs a body element inside an iframe
            
            const converter = new showdown.Converter();
            const html = converter.makeHtml(article.body);

            window.tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(blogHtml);
        } else {
            // @ts-ignore
            console.log(window.tinymce, document.tinymce)
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Couldn't fill out the blog content, reason: ", e);
    }
});
```

When *tinymce* is available to the content script, it seems to be a reference to a DOM element, a body element specifically. Which isn't the TinyMCE instance that has the API methods.

I'm really confused on why the apparently same variable holds different values. I have no trouble setting the contents from devtools console apart from the variable missing if iframe is not inspected beforehand.